# Did the new chrome update break bookmarklets?

Tags: google-chrome

So I have a bunch of bookmarklets and they all worked but when I updated my chromebook, they stopped working and wouldn't activate when I clicked on them. I thought that the administrator might have disabled them but when I tried them on another chromebook that didn't have the latest update, the bookmarklets worked completely fine. Can anyone explain to me what happened?

I tried allowing insecure content on websites because that usually works but they still didn't work so I tried restarting my chromebook to see if that fixes it but they still wouldn't work. I can't think of anything else to try to fix it but I am pretty sure it is the new chrome update because other people are having the same problem that I am having.

Comment: This question doesn't have anything to do with programming, so it's off topic on Stack Overflow. You might have better luck [over on our Super User site instead](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome).

Answer (score 0):

it was probably patched in v115 chrome, sorry